# ejecutar un aplicación en segundo plano

Tags: c#, windows-forms

mi aplicación solo funciona cuando esta abierta en primer plano, la cual quita la utilidad al ordenador, existe alguna manera para ejecutarlo en segundo plano.

Una aplicación que funciona de manera OFFLINE con una base de datos local.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[LINK DE PROYECTO GITHUB](https://github.com/roalroga/SPLANO)

Comment: Pues si no vas a interactuar con un usuario, en lugar de aplicacion crea un [servicio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)

Comment: pasa que esta es una aplicación offline, con una base de datos local Access

Comment: Si es una aplicación WinForms puedes usar [BackgroundWorker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: No se si te tomaste el tiempo de leer el enlace que te dejo @MiguelZarate, porque ese enlace puede que sea la solucion que necesitas. Si no es asi, entonces redacta mejor tu pregunta, ¿que es lo que quieres hacer? por que el codigo que dejas en github no ayuda en nada a entender que estas haciendo. Pregunta: ¿Quieres dejar siempre la app corriendo en segundo plano o solo ciertos procesos de la aplicacion cuando el usuario interectua con el?.

Comment: No comprendo bien a lo que te refieres, ya que Windows es un sistema multi-tarea, por lo que tu aplicación sigue funcionando aunque no esté en primer plano y no tenga el foco, por ejemplo, si haces algún proceso tardado, comprimir un archivo, por decir algo, esta operación continuará recibiendo tiempo de procesador siempre que la aplicación siga ejecutándose, sin importar si está en primer plano o no.